# How to use iTerm along with the default bash terminal?

Tags: bash, iterm

I want to use iTerm with my default bash terminal because there is a lot of customization that i have done to my .bash_profile and I don't want to lose it or perform all the hard work again.

Comment: What makes you believe that using a different SSH client will somehow override your bash_profile?

Comment: i thought iterm might have its own shell and installing it might not replace the original one

Comment: The shell is on the server, not the client.  The interior of a room doesn't change when you look through a different window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up a couple of things here. Note there is no such thing as bash terminal.

iTerm and Terminal are applications that start up a defined program - by default it is `/usr/bin/login`. This program starts a shell (listed in `/etc/shells`) by default this is `/bin/bash`.

bash reads `~/.bash_profile` if it is started by login (or with a `-l` parameter), bash does not care if it is started by iTerm or Terminal. (There might be environment variables set depending on what starts bash e.g. ITERM_* from iTerm and TERM_PROGRAM by both)

iTerm and Terminal store their defaults in different places (both within `~/Library/Preferences`) and do not write to `~/.bash*` files.

Thus your `~/.bash_profile` will be run by both iTerm and Terminal and will not be affected by them except if you test on certain variables

Comment: what if i want to use different bash_profiles/ vimrc for terminal and iTerm?

Comment: you don;t you test on the value of TERM_PROGRAM for bash